# How do I upgrade from Apache NiFi 1.15.3 and earlier to 1.17.0 or 1.18.0?

Tags: apache-nifi

How should I handle the transition from flow.xml.gz to flow.json.gz when upgrading Apache NiFi from versions 1.15.3 and earlier to 1.17.0? Should I opt for an automated migration or manually rename the file to flow.json.gz during the upgrade process?

Answer (score 2):

cruise6, changing the file name to flow.json.gz from the old version of flow.xml.gz will not work, as they are two different formats.

The other alternative you suggested, i.e. automatically transition will work fine.

I migrated from 1.15.1 to 1.16.1 and in the 1.15.1 I only had flow.xml.gz file. After I restarted with the upgrade I see two files flow.xml.gz and flow.json.gz. Both files are updated as I make changes to the flows. But at some point the xml version will go away.